# Style formatting contd

Tags: css

I need to write text in green or red based on:

```
if(str > 0)

{

    document.getElementById('change').style.color = "Green";
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = html[1];

}

else

{
    document.getElementById('change').style.color = "Red";
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = html[1];

}

str = html[2];

str = str.replace("+","");

str = str.replace("-","");

if(str > 0)

{
        document.getElementById('changePercent').style.color = "Green";
                    document.getElementById('changePercent').innerHTML = html[2];

                }

                else

                {
                    document.getElementById('changePercent').style.color = "Red";
                    document.getElementById('changePercent').innerHTML = html[2];

                }
```

But for values -17.91, -5.61, i get both values in the green. Where is the error?

Comment: this is why i prefer jQuery, so much easier to implement these sorts of things

Comment: cou;d u give an example?

Comment: I could be missing something, but aren't you removing the "-"?

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $('p').text();
if (value > 0){
$('p').css('color','green');
}
else {
$('p').css('color','red');
}
```

Simple jQuery

Answer (score 0):

It could be something bizarre about your variable type. I'm only suspicious because your variable is called str.

Comment: Well usually it would figure that you are trying to do a numerical comparison, but it may be worth explicitly casting to float and giving it a test

Comment: OK, how are you getting the value of str in the first place?